# Snowflake Account must be specified error, but it is specified

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below code, I have the account, username, pw, etc, but I'm still seeing the below error:

> raise error_class( sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError:
> (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 251001: Account must be
> specified

I've also tried by changing the `engine` variable in my `created_db_engine` function like below, but I see the same error:

```
engine = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user='USER',
                password='PASSWORD',
                account='ACCOUNT',
                warehouse='WAREHOUSE',
                database='DATABASE',
                schema='SCHEMA'
                )
```

here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas, pd_writer
from pandas import json_normalize
import requests

  
df = 'my_dataframe'

   
def create_db_engine(db_name, schema_name):
    engine = URL(
        account="ab12345.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com",
        user="my_user",
        password="my_pw",
        database="DB",
        schema="PUBLIC",
        warehouse="WH1",
        role="DEV"
    )
    return engine


def create_table(out_df, table_name, idx=False):
    url = create_db_engine(db_name="db", schema_name="skm")
    engine = create_engine(url)
    connection = engine.connect()

    try:
        out_df.to_sql(
            table_name, connection, if_exists="append", index=idx, method=pd_writer
        )

    except ConnectionError:
        print("Unable to connect to database!")

    finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()

    return True

print(df.head)

create_table(df, "reporting")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given the [Snowflake documentation for SqlAlchemy](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/sqlalchemy.html#required-parameters), your **account** parameter should not include **snowflakecomputing.com**.

So you should try with **ab12345.us-west-2** and connector will append the domain part automatically for you.

Comment: thank you this worked

Comment: For me, it only worked with `'ab12345.us-east-2.aws'` meaning that in addition to this answer there had to be `.aws` on the end.